# Upload large files with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using Paperclip as file uploader for my projects. It is very great gem and I have configured it to upload multiple files, convert etc.

All would be very great, but I have a problems when I am uploading big files. When I am uploading 10 images 5MB each, Mozilla is crashing. What I could do avoid it?

Comment: Devise is an authorization framework, it's got nothing to do with file uploads. Please review and mention the gem you're actually using for uploads.

Comment: Thank you for edit. Stupid mistake from me.

Comment: @eugen Not quite: Devise is for authentication, not authorization - refer to [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for an excellent authorization gem.

Comment: @Charles - absolutely correct - I meant authentication, not authorization.

Answer (score 1):

You problem seems to more related to your Mozilla browser than to paperclip. Paperclip only comes into play after the files have been transferred completely between the browser and your webserver.

Comment: Yes, maybe there is problem with Mozilla, but I wont to tell all my webpage visitors to configure Mozilla. Instead of this I need a solution in my RoR project - loading bar or something else.